# Google Docs copy paste formatting / indent question

Tags: google-docs, text-formatting, regex

So say I am taking a YouTube transcript, and copying the whole thing, and then pasting it into a document. The way the transcript is set up with YouTube it's layered like every 5 seconds so its lines of like 4-10 words.

So on YouTube, it's like:

```
Hi hello hi hello hi hello

Hi hello hi hello hi hello

Hi hello hi hello hi hello

Hi hello hi hello hi hello
```

... and so on

Now when I copy everything and do "paste without formatting" it removes that extra blank lines between everything and pastes it. Still lined but more condensed and nothing in between.

But I want more than that. I dont want lines of text at all, I want it to be one large paragraph together. So the above text would read:

```
Hi hello hi hello hi hello Hi hello hi hello hi hello Hi hello hi hello hi hello Hi hello hi hello hi hello...
```

Is there anyway I could do this easily or any solution at all without going in manually and backspacing hundreds of times turning a 20 page lined document into a 3 page filled out doc?

Answer (score 1):

- paste your text
- press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>H</kbd>**
- on **Find** type in **`[\n]`**
- on **Replace with** type in empty space

[image]

- result is:

[image]